# Assign a std::vector to a std::valarray

Tags: c++, c++11, variable-assignment, std, valarray

I have a `vector<vector<double>`, so a table (matrix) of values. Columns contains position and velocity of a planet, so rows stores data of the same planet. I want to transform a row in a `valarray` because I need math operations. Then I want to store the valarrays (the planets) in a vector.
I tried like this:

```
vector<vector<double>> corps_tmp=configFile.get_corps(); // The function returns a vector<vector<double>>

    valarray<double> corpX;
    for (int i(0); i < corps_tmp.size(); i++) {
        corpX = corps_tmp[i]; // I want to save the first row of the vector<vector<double>> on the valarray
        corps.push_back(corpX); // I want to ''add'' the valarray to a vector.
        corpX = 0;
    }
```

This code doesn't works and I obtain an error around the assignment of a vector to a valarray (apparently not permitted).

Is there any way to achieve in a simple way what I tried to do?

Comment: you should use a plain `std::vector<double>` for your matrix and use some formulas to calculate the proper index. `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` screws cache.

Comment: @bamboon I need valarray to create a numerical agorithm that integrates both position and velocity at the same time (so the whole valarray).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To create a valarray from a vector:

```
std::valarray<double> corpX(corps_tmp[i].data(), corps_tmp[i].size());
```

To write the data back into a vector:

```
corps_tmp[i].assign(std::begin(corpX), std::end(corpX));
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `std::begin(std::valarray )` or `std::end(std::valarray )`.Particularly, we have _non-iterator_ arguments when constructing a `std::valarray` from a vector, and _iterator-like_ arguments when assigning to a `std::vector` - in both cases, the expected argument-types are consistent with the type of the object being constructed or assigned to.